# snmp_set_enum_print undefined?

Tags: php, snmp

I have A really simple PHP script that is failing. When I run it, I am getting this message in my apache error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function snmp_set_enum_print()
```

Here is the full PHP script:

```
<?php
snmp_set_enum_print(0);
?>
```

I upgraded my Net-SNMP libraries to v5.5 and I am still getting this error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had to update the /etc/rc.d/rc.snmptrapd to accept unauthorized v3 traps.